# Ionic - Re-use the same HTML template for multiple pages with different content

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am building an Ionic app with multiple pages. A lot of these pages have the same HTML structure, only the content differs. How can I just use one HTML file and fill the content dynamically? Is this done via a controller per page? Or is there a better way to do this?

Here is an example of the HTML code for one page:

```
<ion-view title="Comparison">
<div class="bar bar-subheader bar-stable">
    <h5 class="text-center">Do you have many categories?</h5>
</div>
<ion-content class="has-subheader">
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item ui-sref="bar-chart" class="text-center">Yes</ion-item>
        <ion-item ui-sref="column-chart" class="text-center">No</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

So the parts that need to be dynamic per page are the title, h5 and list items.

Now I have a separate HTML file per page. I then refer to these HTML files in the .state in app.js as shown below.

```
.state('comparison-nb-categories', {
  url: '/',
  templateUrl: 'templates/comparison/nb-categories.html'
})
```

That page can be accessed from another page via an ui-sref as shown below.

```
<ion-item ui-sref="comparison-nb-categories" class="text-center">No</ion-item>
```

Comment: I am trying to find out if the opposite is possible.... to use a single modal class and use different templates to each case. Or does Ionic really need a class for every different modal you make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use one template html for all such pages but different controllers and in this controllers assign right values to model.

```
.state('state1', {
            templateUrl: "templates/page1.html",
            controller: "FirstCtrl",
        })
.state('state2', {
            templateUrl: "templates/page1.html",
            controller: "SecondCtrl",
        });
```

html would be

```
<ion-view title="{{title}}">
<div class="bar bar-subheader bar-stable">
    <h5 class="text-center">{{subheader}}</h5>
</div>
<ion-content class="has-subheader">
    <ion-list ng-repeat="item in items">
        <ion-item ui-sref="{{item.ref}}bar-chart" class="text-center">{{item.name}}</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

FirstCtrl

```
.controller('FirstCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.title = Title1;
    $scope.subheader = Subheader1;
    $scope.items = [{name:'Yes', ref:'bar-chart'},{name:'No', ref:'column-chart'}];
```

SecondCtrl

```
.controller('SecondCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.title = Title2;
    $scope.subheader = Subheader2;
    $scope.items = [{name:'name1', ref:'ref1'},{name:'name2', ref:'ref2'}];
```

I added working example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEpKJE?editors=101

Comment: Thanks for your reaction Olga, but this will not work because the controller is not added to the HTML template. Therefore the variables added to the scope are not accessible.

Comment: @Bert Carremans, check please my example and say if I understood your question wrong.

Comment: or you could use one controller with `switch-case` to select/assign multiple page content, depending on a variable.